# MySQL Update Column from other column in same table

Tags: mysql

I added a new column, supervisor_id, to a USERS table that I need to populate from the same USERS table:

```
ID   |  USERNAME  |  SUPERVISOR_USERNAME  |  SUPERVISOR_ID

1    |  jdoe      |  jsmith               | NULL

2    |  jsmith    |  dduck                | NULL
```

How would I loop through the table to set the supervisor_id = id, like this:

```
ID   |  USERNAME  |  SUPERVISOR_USERNAME  |  SUPERVISOR_ID

1    |  jdoe      |  jsmith               |  2

2    |  jsmith    |  dduck                | NULL
```

I tried the following, but it obviously only set the supervisor_id where the user's supervisor_username was his own username.

```
update users
set supervisor_id = id
where supervisor_username = username
```

Comment: How big is the table?  Just do it manually?

Comment: If the table isn't that big, then I would create a temp copy of users and then create a new table based on the users and copy_of_users into
`CREATE TABLE USERS_IDS ( id int, USERNAME VARCHAR(xxxx),  SUPERVISOR_ID int ); `

Comment: @Pakk , I believe the query would only work if the supervisor has the name as username.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate as the OP needs to copy one column value to another column at **"different row"**. the duplicate question just copy column to column at the same row. Very distinct tasks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can make a self-join with the multiple table `UPDATE` syntax:

```
UPDATE users u
  JOIN users s ON s.SUPERVISOR_USERNAME = u.USERNAME
SET    u.SUPERVISOR_ID = s.ID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da214/1/0).

You should then drop your `SUPERVISOR_NAME` column, which violates [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form); instead, you can make another self-join when you retrieve the data if so desired:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.USERNAME, s.USERNAME AS SUPERVISOR_USERNAME, u.SUPERVISOR_ID
FROM   users u LEFT JOIN users s ON s.ID = u.SUPERVISOR_ID
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04db9/1/0).

Comment: Yes, I'm dropping supervisor_username now that I have their IDs.  Thank you, I think this will do it.

Comment: dang beat me to it gj

Comment: @Pakk: By 10 minutes..?

Comment: Im new to sql :) had to try mine ;P

Comment: Hmm, it only updated about a third of the records - weird.  I verified there were no null or incorrect supervisor_usernames that may not match existing usernames, but the spot check seems ok.

Comment: And, BTW - SQLFIDDLE!  Awesome.

Comment: @KatieM: Can you give an example of a user that was not updated, and include the record for the supervisor too?

Comment: `ID = 4, USERNAME = MACIO, SUPERVISOR_USERNAME = VUHDE` // `ID = 3, USERNAME = VUHDE, SUPERVISOR_USERNAME = LSCHMIDT`  MACIO's record has a null supervisor_id

Comment: @KatieM: Well, that certainly looks as though it should work... could you `SELECT HEX(SUPERVISOR_USERNAME) WHERE ID = 4` and `SELECT HEX(USERNAME) WHERE ID = 3`?

Comment: Yeah, huh?  Something is weird.  I do get a return from that: `6C7363686D696474
7675686465` What is "HEX"?

Comment: I suppose I can just do this in Excel and import the results that way... it's only a one-time deal.

Comment: @KatieM: [`HEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) reveals the encoding actually stored in the computer (in hexadecimal form).  What you have pasted there are the binary encodings of `'lschmidt'` and `'vuhde'`?  Please confirm you entered the commands exactly as I wrote them?

Comment: `SELECT HEX(SUPERVISOR_USERNAME) from users WHERE ID = 3` = `6C7363686D696474`  and `SELECT HEX(SUPERVISOR_USERNAME) from users WHERE ID = 4` = `7675686465`

Comment: Ok - I converted those results from hex to text and they are correct. MACIO's supervisor is VUHDE, but MACIO's supervisor_id did not get updated and is showing null

Comment: @KatieM: I asked for `HEX(USERNAME) FROM users WHERE ID = 3`, not `HEX(SUPERVISOR_USERNAME)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
update Users u
inner join Users temp on
    u.Supervisor_username = temp.UserName
set u.Supervisor_ID = temp.ID
```