# How to retrieve node number based on parent node dynamically from xsd file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database, domxpath

I took the tag names from xsd file and also stored into database but am not able to assign the reference number based on the parent node using php.
my XSD is

```
sample.xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="shipto">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
              <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
            </xs:sequence>

          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My PHP code is

```
<?php
 $xsdstring ="sample.xsd";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhitespace = false;

$xsdstring = $doc->load($xsdstring);
$doc->loadXML(mb_convert_encoding($xsdstring, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($xsdstring)));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$mysql_hostname = "localhost"; // Example : localhost
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "sample_db";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$mysql_database};host={$mysql_hostname};port=3306", $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
$num=1;      
function echoElements($indent, $elementDef) {
  global $doc, $xpath,$elements,$dbh,$num,$sql;

  $elements =  $indent . $elementDef->getAttribute('name') ."\n";

  $elementDefs = $xpath->evaluate("xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element", $elementDef);

    $sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`,ref_num) VALUES (?,?)");
    $sql->execute(array($elements ,$num));

  foreach($elementDefs as $elementDef) {
     $test=echoElements("" , $elementDef);

  }
}

$elementDefs = $xpath->evaluate("/xs:schema/xs:element");
foreach($elementDefs as $elementDef) {
    echoElements("", $elementDef);
}                       
?>
```

what I expect is

```
id     name         ref_num
1      shiporder       0 //refers that it is root node
2      orderperson     1 //refers the id of its parent node(shiporder)
3      shipto          1 //refers the id of its parent node(shiporder)
4      name            3 //refers the id of its parent node(shipto)
5      address         3
.....
```

Is there any idea to create my table in this format dynamically?

Help me to Solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: edit your question, include all relevant information, like XSD, code.

Comment: Not while you are using domdocument/xpath. Its easy with the event parser though - http://php.net/manual/en/example.xml-structure.php

Comment: Thank you. The code is working fine, but only for XML files. Can you say how to get parent node of an element in an XSD file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put the names of the parent nodes of an element in another field of the table as parent_name

```
id     name            parent_name       ref_num
1      shiporder       root                0 
2      orderperson     shiporder           1  
3      shipto          shiporder           1 
4      name            shipto              3 
5      address         shipto              3
.....
```

And then you can insert the ref_num by using the query as given in the following link

[MySQL Update Column from other column in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684628/mysql-update-column-from-other-column-in-same-table)

Comment: Thanks Kavya am struggling to take parent node from the XSD file. Give some idea to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append root, child elements, sub child elements in an array. Search sub child elements until the number of child elements. return the array in MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code to get the parent node of each element and post it into the database

```
$elements =  $indent . $elementDef->getAttribute('name') ."\n";

$parent = $elements->xpath("parent::*"); // or $elements->xpath( '..' );

$elementDefs = $xpath->evaluate("xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element", $elementDef);

$sql = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`,ref_num,`parent_node`) VALUES (?,?,?)");

$sql->execute(array($elements,$num,$parent));
```